# C# Regular Expression - Adding Special Characters

Tags: regex

I was wondering what is the best way to include backslash and other special characters in a group?

example:

```
"message":"\"rock on\" \\,,/,[-_-]";
```

help me on my regex

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 \\-~!@#$%^*()_+{}:|?`;',\\./\\[\\]]+
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?  what exactly is the "example" you've given, and what do you want to do with the regex? What's the goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just escape those that need to be escaped and add those, that don't need to:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 \\\-~!@#$%^*()_+{}:|"?`;',./[\]]+
```

To elaborate a bit:
You only need to escape `\`, `]` and `-` inside a character group.

Using C#, it would look like this:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z0-9 \\\-~!@#$%^*()_+{}:|""?`;',./[\]]+");
```

Comment: The quote should work, too. I updated my answer with a C# sample.

Comment: doesn't matter. the quote was passed as \x26amp; I'll just have to replace

Comment: @RaghavKhunger: Correct, I hit the wrong key when posting this. You have to escape `]` and not `[`.